# How can a Sonos customer view the Households associated with their account?

Tags: sonos

The Sonos cloud call 'households' usually returns a single household, but sometimes it returns two (makes sense), sometimes it returns two identical households (?) and sometimes it returns zero households (??). How can a registered Sonos user view the households associated with their accounts? What can I tell the user that somehow has zero households? I don't see anything like this on the Sonos 'myaccount' page, but then my personal account only has a single household.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a call returns zero households, it usually means that a user's household(s) is offline. You can suggest in your app that the user confirm that things are working correctly in the Sonos app.

As for a user being able to get an overview of their household situation, that's currently not an option, but I'll take your suggestion back to the team.